# Triple handshake attack - what are the implications of not supporting RFC 7627: "Session Hash and Extended Master Secret Extension"?

Tags: tls

The referenced RFC details a mitigation to what appears to be the ability to compromise a TLS connection through an attack known as the 'triple handshake attack'.

How serious is this vulnerability? How could this vulnerability be exploited and what would the impact be?

The related RFC for this can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7627

Comment: The publicity(?) website for this research&paper is https://www.mitls.org/pages/attacks/3SHAKE which has explanations and several examples. Note TLS1.3, finally completed last year, drops resumption entirely (in favor a new mechanism using derived temporary PSK), and thus when and where implemented fixes this and similar problems.

Comment: The abstract and introduction describe the exploit. What part of that is unclear? It's a MITM attack that would work on servers with valid PKI certificates as long as the attacker has a valid cert of its own, so it's fairly serious if your clients would accept the attacker's cert.

Comment: I'm just trying to make security.stackexchange.com a better place @DoubleD.